# Rails: undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass, but value (without strftime) returns OK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, strftime

I have an odd problem with a (rails 3) activerecord query.

If I submit query #1 (below) to the view (below) everything works fine...but if I submit query #2 (below), I get "undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass"

...However, if I strip the strtime string away from query #2, it returns the unformatted time just fine.

"Professional specialties" is a has_many :through table; I'm assuming that has something to do with it...but I can't quite figure out what.

Any idea what's going on? All suggestions appreciated:

Query #1 (works fine)

```
@professionals = Professional.all(:include => :user, :conditions => ["users.first_name = ? AND users.last_name = ?", params[:name][:first], params[:name][:last]])
```

Query #2 (breaks strtime)

```
 @professionals = Professional.all(:include => [:user, :professional_specialties], :conditions => ["professional_specialties.profession_type_id = ?", params[:profession_type]] )
```

View

```
<% @professionals.each do |p| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to("%s %s" % [p.user.first_name, p.user.last_name], p) %></td>
    <td><%= p.business %></td>
    <td><%= p.user.role.name %></td>
    <td><%= p.user.created_at %></td>
    <td><%= p.user.last_sign_in_at.strftime("%Y") %></td>
  </tr>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My best guess would be that the two queries give you different resultsets. In the second resultset, one or more of the users has a `NULL` value for the `last_sign_in_at` column.

Run `Professional.all(...).map(&:users)` in the Rails console (`rails console` in your application directory), and double-check that they all have valid timestamps.

Comment: @Zabba: I think you meant `<%= p.user.last_sign_in_at.try(:strftime, "%Y") %>`

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Deleted my comment.

Comment: Ach - of course. Many thanks, there was a hidden entry with a nil value.

Comment: Shouldn't nil.strftime return nil without an error message? Otherwise we need to set unless nil conditions, which is annoying ...

Comment: @Augustin Absolutely not. `strftime` is not a valid method for `nil`. It would be a very bad idea to add methods from `Time` to `nil`, because where would you draw the line? What about `String` and `Array`? By that logic, shouldn't `nil.downcase` or `nil.first` also return nil without an error message?

Comment: Right, it doesn't make sense to apply methods to `nil`. Actually, I've seen an option in Rails saying `# Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil. config.whiny_nils = true` in `development.rb`. Instead, we should be able to call `strftime(user.created_at, '%d/%m/%y')` so that `strftime(nil, '%d %m %y') --> nil`. It's actually very easy to write!